# Automatic update of list data upon change

Tags: flutter, google-sheets

I have built an app in Flutter that shows a ListView of data pulled from google sheets. What I would like to do is have the list automatically refresh itself when data is changed on google sheets. I'm not sure if it is possible, but any help would be appreciated.

```
class BodFullList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodFullListState createState() => _BodFullListState();
}

class _BodFullListState extends State<BodFullList> {

  final StreamController _streamController = StreamController();

  List<DGL> dgl = [];
  int index = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    getDGL();
   }

  Future getDGL({int? index}) async {
    final dgl = await BodSheetsApi.getAll();

    setState(() {
      this.dgl = dgl;
     });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text(MyApp.title),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body:RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: getDGL,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dgl.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Card (
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => BodEntryEdit(),
                    settings: RouteSettings(
                    arguments: dgl[index],
                  )
                )
                );

              },
              title: Text(dgl[index].loc)
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    )
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the informations you have provided are not enough. But, as i imagine, you are fetching the data once and not listening. To listen to changes, you need to use websockets. I remember that GoogleSheet allows to use webhooks from there, you can implement whatever you want.